# What is the DevOps term for 'read-only-deployment' pattern of a web application?

Tags: testing, deployment, devops, read-only

There is a lot of [optimism](https://www.thoughtworks.com/insights/blog/implementing-blue-green-deployments-aws) around [Blue-Green](https://docs.cloudfoundry.org/devguide/deploy-apps/blue-green.html) [deployments](https://cloudnative.io/blog/2015/02/the-dos-and-donts-of-bluegreen-deployment/), particularly from luminaries like [Martin Fowler](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/BlueGreenDeployment.html).

The challenge with a financial services application, is that to make a blue-green deployment work, you have to guarantee that the old app will still be able to transact whilst the new app is being deployed - which requires testing the old app in light of the new code going in. (Potentially double the testing).

So basically blue-green deployments are infeasible for large financial services applications because you double your regression testing cost just to have extra availability during the release. Instead what you need is a compromise position, where you put the application into 'read-only' mode during the deployment, which reduces risk but still maximises availability.

What some designs do is a 'reporting database' with a web-app read-only mode - so the web app can still work providing information, but not transact.

When I google for this - I can't find this pattern, which makes me think I've got the wrong term.

My question is: **What is the DevOps term for 'read-only-deployment' mode of a web application?**

Comment: Not everything is a well-defined pattern.  There are some things that don't have "terms."

Comment: This actually *does* have a term, it's "Immutable Deployments".  I don't see how it was closed as "opinion based".

Comment: Thanks Paul - if you have a reference for that then we can get this reopened.